# What are the width of data/control/address bus for a 32-bit CPU?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

Are they exactly 32bits for a 32-bit CPU?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a 32-bit CPU I would expect the width of the data bus to be 32 bits. In addition, I would expect the size of the address bus to be 32 bits. However, you cannot count on that being true. For example, the 8088 was sold as a 16-bit CPU but it had a 8 bit path to memory.

In summary, they usually are 32 bits but they might not be.